# Core-Plot - Is it possible to have line graph with plot symbols of different fill color

Tags: ios, core-plot

I've different filters that I use for plotting my graph. Based on filter selection fill color of the plot symbol changes. In the list of filters one option is "All", when user select all I want to show all the data in one line but also want to preserve fill color.

To make it more understandable,

Let's say I've three buttons, - 1)Male 2)Female 3)All

When user select Male I am plotting graph of all Males data with white fill color,

When user select Female I am plotting graph of all Female data with pink fill color,

When user select All, I want to plot all Male and Female on one line and also want to keep white for male and pink for female.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method to return the desired plot symbol at each index. The `-reloadData` method forces the plot to reload the symbols in addition to the plot data.